# how to join element in list by index?

Tags: python, list

I have list:

```
['0.125', '0', 'A']
['0.5', '0', 'B', ' A']
['0.75', '0', 'C']
['0.5', '0.5', 'D', ' C', 'A']
```

I want to get

```
['0.125', '0', 'A']
['0.5', '0', 'B']
['0.5', '0', 'A']
['0.75', '0', 'C']
['0.5', '0.5', 'D']
['0.5', '0.5', 'C']
['0.5', '0.5', 'A']
```

Any guide for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
[sub[:2] + [elem] for sub in yourlist for elem in sub[2:]]
```

Demo:

```
>>> yourlist = [
...     ['0.125', '0', 'A'],
...     ['0.5', '0', 'B', ' A'],
...     ['0.75', '0', 'C'],
...     ['0.5', '0.5', 'D', ' C', 'A'],
... ]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> [sub[:2] + [elem] for sub in yourlist for elem in sub[2:]]
[['0.125', '0', 'A'], ['0.5', '0', 'B'], ['0.5', '0', ' A'], ['0.75', '0', 'C'], ['0.5', '0.5', 'D'], ['0.5', '0.5', ' C'], ['0.5', '0.5', 'A']]
>>> pprint(_)
[['0.125', '0', 'A'],
 ['0.5', '0', 'B'],
 ['0.5', '0', ' A'],
 ['0.75', '0', 'C'],
 ['0.5', '0.5', 'D'],
 ['0.5', '0.5', ' C'],
 ['0.5', '0.5', 'A']]
```

Comment: I got this error "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects", Please suggest.

Comment: @ThanaDaray: I'll add a demo; `yourlist` is a list of all your input lists, not a single list.